# .htaccess Wordpress and NodeJS running alongside

Tags: node.js, wordpress, .htaccess, routes, centos7

i'm trying to add alongside an old Wordpress website a route that servers a NodeJS Instance.
The thing is that I want to run both Wordpress and Node.js on the same server but on different routes.

Wordpress is running here `http://example.com`

Node is running here `http://example.com:61000/oferta-de-pret-traduceri`

`.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/oferta-de-pret-traduceri$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/oferta-de-pret-traduceri/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:61000/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't know Wordpress that well nor do I know .htaccess like I should in this case and I don't want to move everything to NGINX unless I have to.

I want my Node.js instance to run on `http://example.com/oferta-de-pret-traducerii` not on `http://example.com:61000`.

Also Wordpress trows a 404 error if I try to access `http://example.com/oferta-de-pret-traduceri`

Hope someone has encountered this kind of situation and has an easy solution.

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: You mention nginx but mod_rewrite is from Apache. Which web server are you actually using?

Comment: I wanted to move everything from Apache to Nginx because that is the only way i know how to run both Wordpress and Node altogether. Current config is with .htaccess so it's Apache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off with `ProxyPassMatch` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch

`ProxyPassMatch "^/oferta-de-pret-traduceri$" "http://127.0.0.1:61000/$1"`

The docs for mod_rewrite say this:

> Consider using either ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch whenever possible in
>   preference to mod_rewrite.

If you cannot use ProxyPass, try this rule:

`RewriteRule ^oferta-de-pret-traduceri http://127.0.0.1:61000$1 [P,L]`

I used this tool to test: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

If your node app expects 'oferta-de-pret-traduceri' to be in the URL, you will need this rule:

`RewriteRule ^oferta-de-pret-traduceri http://127.0.0.1:61000/oferta-de-pret-traduceri$1 [P,L]`

Comment: Tried to add replace the RewriteRule with $1 in the end but got Internal Server Error

Comment: You'll need to provide the apache error log in this case. Maybe you don't have mod_proxy loaded?

Comment: [Thu Oct 19 14:28:29.115623 2017] [core:alert] [pid 29288:tid 140576326366976] [client 188.26.5.98:65354] /home/translat/public_html/.htaccess: ProxyPassMatch not allow
ed here

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you can't use ProxyPass in a .htaccess, I thought we were in a virtual host block. Can you move the config to the virtual host?

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea how to move .htaccess rules to httpd.conf

Comment: I've edited my answer to include another RewriteRule option

Comment: Another thing is how do I go about a POST Method for the Form that is on that page ?

Comment: All your URIs in your node app need to become relative to '/oferta-de-pret-traduceri' so that resources, form submit path, etc., go via this URI.

Comment: This is great, everything is working. Thank you so much @Dave Irvine